# INVALID_CLIENT: Invalid client spotify url using.env

Tags: node.js, api

I'm trying to put my client and secret client API keys in a .env file.

Code was working fine before i moved to the .env file

I've used npm install dotenv and it's coming up in my package.json file

```
require('dotenv').config();

var client_id = 'process.env.CLIENT_'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'process.env.CLIENT_S'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri
```

I can't anything that I've done wrong.

Hoping somebody can help me on this.

My .env file looks like this

```
 CLIENT_=
 CLIENT_S=
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've put the process.env.CLIENT properties inside quotes? That will treat them as strings.

Comment: When I remove the quotes I'm getting a new error "Missing required parameter: client_id"

Comment: That error is probably coming later in your script. Have you set your CLIENT_ and CLIENT_S in your .env file? E.g. CLIENT_=Bob12345

Comment: Yeah they are set I'm caaling it from here to authorise which looks correct to me and was working before I tried to put in .env file res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));